# Apache Multiple VirtualDocumentRoot for Single Wildcard domain *.dev

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost, vhosts, mod-vhost-alias

I'm working with Virtualhosts and a local catch-all domain TLD and I need 3 use-cases to work simultaneously, but so far, I've only been able to get two to work at a time.

I need for three different test domains to be able to access their respective document root.

1. **Case 1:** test1.dev --> /path/to/www/SomeFolderName (an override using it's own unique folder name and virtualhost file)
2. **Case 2:** *.dev --> /path/to/www/%0 (full url including .dev, so test2.dev points to /path/to/www/test2.dev )
3. **Case 3:** *.dev --> /path/to/www/%1 (full url *excluding* .dev, so test3.dev points to /path/to/www/test3 )

So, I need two wildcard situations for any domain like test2.dev or test3.dev, use   `VirtualDocumentRoot "/path/www/%0"` if it exists or `VirtualDocumentRoot "/share/www/%1"` if that exists instead.

Right now, either case 2 or case 3 works depending what is loaded first, but not both at the same time. **How can I have 1 catch all domain select only the existing document root?**

Answer (score 0):

It's not really supported to have Apache change the document root based on whether or not the directory actually exists.  I think you will have better luck standardizing the document roots so that they are all `/share/www/testX.dev` and creating symbolic links from `/share/www/testX.dev` to `/share/www/testX` when necessary.  You could even create the symlinks from a custom 404 handler.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead try to use one single document root for all directories and have mod_rewrite check for existence of the folders and/or files (using [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with `-f`or `-d` as `CondPattern`) and [rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) the URLs, so that the correct files are retrieved. This would work with wildcard domains and have quite flexible rules on which folder to use when.